# Chinese characters function R studio

Tags: r, function, character-encoding, character, chinese-locale

I am trying to do text mining in Chinese with R.

In my data set, I have a column with people's comment like  "连锁店购买的". And I have 2 other columns that I created thanks to JiebaR. These hold the segmented message ("连锁店", "购买", "的") and the keywords from these messages ("连锁店", "购买"). The keyword selection removes "不"("no" in Chinese) so I am trying to fetch it back from the words and add it to the keywords. Simple, right ?

To have a clean code, I put all my functions in a separate file and source it in my main file. And NOW something VERY weird happens : the function works when it's in the main file but doesn't work when it's in the file that I source ! (I just copied and pasted the function from my main to the "function" file and run the source(...) line...).

```
fetchingNeg <- function(df){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if ("不" %in% unlist(df[i,]$words)){
      df[i,]$keywords <- list(append(unlist(df[i,]$keywords),"不"))
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found the error : Encoding ! 
There was a character c that I knew was "不" but when I was doing print("不" == c) it would give FALSE... "不" is not encoded in UTF-8 in this case, so to make my code work I had to change it to

```
    fetchingNeg <- function(df){
       for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
          # "不" is "\u{4e0d}" in UTF-8
          if ("\u{4e0d}" %in% unlist(df[i,]$words)){
             df[i,]$keywords <- list(append(unlist(df[i,]$keywords),"\u{4e0d}"))
          }
       }
       return(df)
    }
```